# Detect browser inactivity at the browser level on any website

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

We are a library. We have computers made for users to make quick references to either find books or use a 3rd party application.

We are using EDGE on Windows 8. We can be flexible if there is another browser.

Is there a way to setup an inactivity tracker so that no matter what website the user leaves off on we can redirect the browser back to the homepage after 2 minutes of inactivity.

I'm assuming this is a software solution since we can't control the source on the 3rd party sites.

Comment: I don't think that Microsoft Edge, as in the browser by that name, is available on Windows 8. IE11 does have an earlier version of the "Edge" rendering engine (it's confusing) so this might make sense with just the internet explorer tag.

Comment: I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and @Katana314 is correct. Microsoft Edge (not to be confused with the 'edge' document mode) is only available on Windows 10. Perhaps your Windows 8/8.1 machine has been updated to Windows 10.